# Can you define recursive type hints in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I have an alias for a type in Python:

```py
from typing import Tuple, Dict, Union

SelectedModelArgs = Dict[
    str,
    Union[
        str,
        float,
        Tuple[float, float],
        Dict[str, Union[str, float, Tuple[float, float]]],
    ],
]
```

At present this allows for a dictionary with str to str, float, a tuple of floats or a nested dictionary of the same type. Is there a way to define this recursively to allow arbitrary nesting?

e.g.

```py
SelectedModelArgs = Dict[
    str,
    Union[
        str,
        float,
        Tuple[float, float],
        SelectedModelArgs,
    ],
]
```

When I try this I get IDE errors:

- Pylance: "SelectedModelArgs" is not defined
- Mypy: Cannot resolve now "SelectedModelArgs" (possible cyclic definition)

Adding `from __future__ import annotations` to the top of the file does not resolve these (as it does with using a class name within a class definition).

I have also tried using the code example above but with the nested `"SelectedModelArgs"` as a string (as noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53845083/2012446)). This resolves the pylance error, but not the mypy error.

Comment: The immediate issue is that the definition is an ordinary Python assignment, not an annotation, with an expression that depends on calls to `type.__get_class_item__`. Like any other expression, you can't use the name `SelectedModelArgs` on the right if it hasn't been defined yet.

Comment: Assuming you can get the definition, *then* you run into the next problem of `mypy` not handling recursive type definitions (yet).

Comment: [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58377361/5986907)

Comment: Thanks @joe, yes those questions are pretty similar. Assuming nothing has changed it looks like mypy still doesn't support this.